# How to validate number interval from keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im letting the user to input a number to a field and i am trying to validate the number input within a range om numbers.

Im using the `keyup()` to get the value while user is typing, i think the problem i that jQuery dosent se the number as 30 when the user first type 3 directly after the 0. Thats why the `alert()`is trigger each time i press  a number.

How can i solve this?

This is my code:

```
function from_south(val) {
        var parsed_val = parseInt(val)
        if(parsed_val > 0 || parsed_val <= 30){
            alert('between 0-30')
        }

    }


    $('.deviation-south').on('keyup',function(){
        var degree = $(this).val()
        from_south(degree)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean logic is off, and it will make the `if` condition always true. `||` is an OR, meaning only one of the two conditions has to be true. Now try to think of a number where neither would be true: do you see the problem?

What you want is the opposite: a check where the number is *out* of the valid range:

```
if (parsed_val <= 0 || parsed_val > 30) {
   alert('your number should be between 1 and 30');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but I thought I'd show you a way of creating validation over multiple numerical inputs with a single bit of versatile code. You can create `max` and `min` attributes and use these as your limits, by adding the class `.validation-numerical` the script will then check multiple inputs.

The script below allows you to add spans with error messages, which appear on invalid input, or just use colour feedback for the input text.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add keyup event to all validation-numerical inputs
$("input.validation-numerical").on('keyup', function() {

  // Get value of input, max and min
  var current = $(this).val();
  var min = parseInt($(this).attr("min"));
  var max = parseInt($(this).attr("max"));

  // Compare the max and min with the current value
  // Using && to require both statements to be true
  if (current > min && current <= max) {
  
    // Switch classes for parent wrapper if it matches
    $(this).parent(".input-wrapper.validate").addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid");
    // Add validation classes to input itself
    $(this).addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid");

  } else {
  
    // Switch classes for parent wrapper if it matches
    $(this).parent(".input-wrapper.validate").addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid");
    // Add validation classes to input itself
    $(this).addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid");
    
  }


});
```

```css
.validation-numerical {
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.valid {
  color: black;
}

.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.validation-error {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.invalid > .validation-error {
  opacity: 1;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>

  <label>Validation with message and wrapper (0-30)</label>
  <div class="input-wrapper validate">
    <input id="degress" class="validation-numerical" min="0" max="30">
    <span class="validation-error" for="degrees">Must be between 0 and 30.</span>
  </div>

  <hr>


  <label>Validation with message and wrapper (5-15)</label>
  <div class="input-wrapper validate">
    <input id="degress" class="validation-numerical" min="5" max="15">
    <span class="validation-error" for="degrees">Must be between 5 and 15.</span>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <label>Validation with color only (0-30)</label>
  <input id="degress" class="validation-numerical" min="0" max="30">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is working fine, you just need to adjust your conditions. You only want to trigger the alert if the number is bigger than 30 or below 0.

```js
function from_south(val) {
    var parsed_val = parseInt(val)
    if (parsed_val > 30 || parsed_val < 0) {
        alert('between 0-30');
    }
}

$('.deviation-south').on('keyup', function() {
    var degree = $(this).val()    
    from_south(degree);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="input number (0-30)" class="deviation-south">
</form>
```